# Generate PDF's Pages with a background image

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

I'm generating a pdf with Django. This is the code

```
def generar_pdf(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mi_archivo.pdf"'

    buffer = BytesIO()
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=letter)
    contenido = [
        {"spaceBefore": 0, "spaceAfter": 15, "texto": "text 1", "tipo": 1, "negrita": False},
        {"spaceBefore": 0, "spaceAfter": 0, "texto": "text 2", "tipo": 2, "negrita": False},
        {"spaceBefore": 15, "spaceAfter": 15, "texto": "text 3", "tipo": 3, "negrita": False},
        {"spaceBefore": 0, "spaceAfter": 0, "texto": "text 4", "tipo": 2, "negrita": False},
        {"spaceBefore": 15, "spaceAfter": 0, "texto": "text 5", "tipo": 3, "negrita": False},
         ...
    ]

    flowables = []

    for item in contenido:

        parrafo = Paragraph(item['texto'], ParagraphStyle(
                                name=name,
                                fontName='Helvetica',
                                fontSize=18,
                                alignment=TA_LEFT,
                                spaceBefore=item['spaceBefore'],
                                spaceAfter=item['spaceAfter']
                            ))
        flowables.append(parrafo)
            
    doc.build(flowables)

    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()

    response.write(pdf)
    return response
```

In this pdf, I need each page to have a background image.

I tried using PageTemplate this way:

```
frame = Frame(inch, inch, doc.width - 2 * inch, doc.height - 2 * inch)
template = PageTemplate(id='background', frames=[frame], onPage=add_background)
doc.addPageTemplates([template])
```

But it only apply in the first page, and no to the others.In addition, it reduces the size where the information is displayed but i don't know why.

Comment: That should work, but your `add_background` function should not be using flowables to place the image.  Just draw straight on the canvas.  If the image is large, you can use `beginForm`/`endForm` to "capture" the image, and `doForm` to "replay" it on each page.